# Integration of connected variable

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In my research, I am trying to Model an Ebby Current Braking system based on W. R. Smythe work ([On Eddy Currents in a Rotating Disk](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/81101/1/06436528.pdf))

In this paper the Eddy Currents Torque can be estimated using the following integration:
$$
T = \frac{\omega c b \gamma \Phi^2}{\pi^2 a^4} \times \int_{c-a}^{c+a} 
\left( r^2 \sin{\theta_1} - \frac{a^2 A^2 r^2 \sin{\theta_1}}{c^2 r^2 + A^4 - 2 A^2 r c \cos{\theta_1}} \right) dr
$$
where $\theta_1$ and $r$ are connected by the relation:
$$
r^2 + c^2 — 2 r c \cos{\theta_1} = a^2
$$
Note that all parameters are constants with the exception of $\theta_1$ and $r$

So, I need some help in at least how the first term ($r^2 \sin(\theta_1)$) is integrated.
My field is Mechanical Engineering and I think that I do not have enough mathematical background when it comes to integration of connected variables.

Comment: What happens if you replace $2rc\cos\theta_1$ in the denominator with $r^2+c^2-a^2$?